# Refresh content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to refresh the content of a div with jquery. I have this code but it always says the data and data_check doesn't match while they do when I alert them...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    pageLoad();
});
function reloadPage()
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        pageLoad();
    },5000);
}

function pageLoad()
{
    var data_check = $("div.portlet-body").html().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    $.post("paginas/overzicht_sub.php",
        function(data){
            var data_output = data.replace(/\s+/g, '')
            if(data_output==data_check)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $("div.portlet-body").html(data);
            }
        });
    reloadPage();
}
```

Can someone help? I don't see the problem...

Comment: You can use `setTimeout(pageLoad ,5000);` directly instead of the unneeded `reloadPage();` call.

Comment: I don't see the problem.......!!!!!!????????

Comment: Are you sure? `console.log(escape(data_output));
console.log(escape(data_check));`

Comment: Am I missing something? You already did the heavy lifting by getting the data from the server. Why the extra check? Why not just update the div html irrespective of whether the returned html is the same as the div html or not?

Comment: I agree with jaq. If you really want to make that check then it should be, in my opinion, on server side.

Comment: I did the extra check because it's also a platform to edit stuff and when it's all the time refreshing it can cause problems...

Comment: Please copy/paste the exact(!) values of data_check and data_output before executing the .replace, preferrably included in quotes, so that leading and trailing white space can be seen easily

Comment: Instead of comparing the data, associate an incrementing version number with it. When you post, send the version number as a parameter, and have the server only return data if the current version is higher than the parameter.

Comment: devnull69 is probably on the right track. May also be newline characters or something to that effect. Everything else looks correct.

Comment: Ok I found the problem! There was a A-tag that always ended when there was no A-tag started. In the HTML (data_check) was that tag deleted and in the data not. Many thanks for the responses, I try to do it the next time with versions!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem! There was a A-tag that always ended when there was no A-tag started. In the HTML (data_check) was that tag deleted and in the data not. Many thanks for the responses, I try to do it the next time with versions!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the replace statement in pageLoad()

```
function pageLoad(){
  var data_check = $("div.portlet-body").html(); 
  $.post("aginas/overzicht_sub.php", function(data){
     if(data_output==data){
       return false;
     }else{
       $("div.portlet-body").html(data);
     }
   });  
   reloadPage();
}
```